# UNKNOWN customName ImageAlpha error in logs for MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-motionlayout

I've just started working on MotionLayout and it's really easy so far and I'm getting the required output too. But log is filled with errors *E/MotionPaths: UNKNOWN customName ImageAlpha*

[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout) also writes

> motion:attributeName is required and must match an object with getter and setter methods. The getter and setter much match a specific pattern.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

motion_layout.xml

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <Transition
            motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
            motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start">

        <OnSwipe
                motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
                motion:touchAnchorId="@id/store_viewpager"
                motion:touchAnchorSide="top" />
        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                    motion:framePosition="60"
                    motion:motionTarget="@id/tab_image_view">
                <CustomAttribute
                        motion:attributeName="imageAlpha"
                        motion:customIntegerValue="255" />
            </KeyAttribute>
            <KeyAttribute
                    motion:framePosition="90"
                    motion:motionTarget="@id/tab_image_view">
                <CustomAttribute
                        motion:attributeName="imageAlpha"
                        motion:customIntegerValue="0" />
            </KeyAttribute>
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
                android:id="@+id/tab_image_view"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
                android:id="@+id/tab_image_view"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is saying it cant find "imageAlpha". Your customAttributes 
implies you have a method setImageAlpha(int) on "@+id/tab_image_view".

Assuming it is an ImageView that it would work but only back to api 16. 
Alpha is a little more generic operating from 0.0 to 1.0 and is on View. 
You do not need a custom attribute for it. android:alpha="0"

To help further what is the View? (ImageView?)
What device level?

Comment: yes it's an ImageView. Now I'm using KeyFrameSet for the alpha to be set from frameposition 60 - 90, with same custom attribute.
API level 20. min set to 21

Comment: I did not notice...
You do not define a starting and ending value add 
 <CustomAttribute
                        motion:attributeName="imageAlpha"
                        motion:customIntegerValue="0" />

to the start and end constraintset

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't quite understand. Would you be able to update the answer with the code please?

Comment: Add   
<CustomAttribute
    motion:attributeName="imageAlpha"
     motion:customIntegerValue="123" />
as a tag in the the two <Constraint> tags

Comment: CustomAttributes are already set in KeyAttributes, should those be added again?

Comment: @hoford I have a similar case in which I handle a custom attribute animation with KeyAttribute's. It works perfect but I do get E/MotionPaths: UNKNOWN customName errors. Defining the custom attribute at also Constraint section would break my animation logic. Is it okay to ignore this error log?

Comment: Yes. The error long is a mistake. (It was logging it was not a standard attribute)